# Embedding credentails in url to load website using selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I need to load URL which has authentication pop up. I used http://username:password@exampl.com format to access the website via selenium webdriver on chrome browser.

But this support seems t be **dropped in latest chrome browser**, So loading the url is not successful. Browser keeps loading for a long time with no response from server.

Is there any alternate way to overcome authentication pop-up with selenium webdrier ? I know we can use sikui,autoit etc.But i need to run the **same code on many platforms - Win/Mac/mobile/tablet.**

So please let know how to overcome this.

Comment: Which version of selenium are you on ? Also, version of chromedriver used.?

Comment: Using Chrome browser version 59 on android device. Selenium server 2.53.1 and chrome driver 2.31

Answer (score 0):

I am using Selenium 3.4.0 and Chromedriver 2.31, and loading a URL with authentication credentials works fine for me.

Comment: Using Chrome version 59 on android device. Selenium server 2.53.1 and chrome driver 2.31

Comment: May i know your chrome browser version used

Comment: I tested on Chrome 59 and 60, both.
I think you should upgrade Selenium to 3.4

Answer (score 0):

As per I know chorme stop URL authentication from chrome 60.x version.

You can try below code or downgrade your chrome version

The Alert Method, `authenticateUsing()` lets you skip the Http Basic Authentication box.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

Hope it help you :)